# search box control in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

how to add a searchbox control in windows Phone 8.1?

i had used search box in WP8 like as below

How to use this in Windows Phone 8.1?

Please let me know if any new controls or new namespaces to add.?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,8,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="SearchPanel">
                    <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="Search" x:Name="tbxSearch"  Width="340"
                                     ActionIcon="/Images/appbar.feature.search.rest.png"
                                     ActionIconTapped="Search_ActionIconTapped"/>
                    <Image  x:Name="speaker" Source="/Images/microphone1.png" Height="48" Width="48" MouseLeftButtonDown="speaker_MouseLeftButtonDown_1"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: If you're using WinRT, then Silverlight controls aren't compatible. You'll have to find a different search box.

Comment: Hello, @KooKiz Iam searching for WinRT , i found one but it is working only with Windows 8.1 not working with Windows Phone 8.1, If u find any one compatible with WP 8.1 lease let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `System.Windows.Controls.Orientation` Namespace for these are the control. Then you can refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/bg182890.aspx ,
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-phonetextbox-in-depth for other clarifications

Comment: It is working with WP 8 and WP SL 8.1, , But i want it for WP 8.1